# Insert into query returning "unknown field name: content type" error

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I have added two tables in my access db, one of which is an online (SharePoint) table. I have written the following query to move all my data from the online table to a local table but I keep getting the error in the attached image. I have even cross checked the column names and data types, but I found no issues there.

Local table - mywizgovLocal

SharePoint table - myWizGovSP

The code:

```
INSERT INTO mywizgovLocal 
SELECT * FROM myWizGovSP
```

The Error:

[image]

Comment: Could remove the local table then try VBA TransferDatabase method to import to local table. Or maybe just right click on linked table and click 'Convert to Local Table'.

Comment: thanks for quick response @June7 , although i can't convert the linked table to a local one coz the data in it needs to by synced online for some auto email functionality...
however i got it working by just copying the table and pasting it as a local (structure only) table and then running the same query. Guess there was some issue with some data type.
thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

First make sure the columns' datatype are matched to each other.

Specify your columns like:

```
Insert into mywizgovLocal(id, birthday, salary) Select id, bdate, sal from myWizGovSP;
```

Comment: thanks for response @Rezu , however i got the code working by just copying and pasting the linked table as a local one.